What should I conquer as Britain?
I don't want it a WC. I wanted more like historical Britain, happening. But, always the people says that I have to conquer France in some kind or another to be able to conquer the World. But I'm not into this, as I saw that France is a player too much difficult to just take down even with allies. I should show up what I want, I want to make Britain Great Again by 1550's without sacrificing too much of british flavor invading every province in Europe for example.
Maybe you can help.
